# Нарисовать график Строфоиды в Делфи

Tags: delphi, функции, график

Как нарисовать график Строфоиды в Делфи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вот так

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  const mash = 100;
  begin
  a:=StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
    b:=StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    x0:=Image1.Width div 2;
    y0:=Image1.Height div 2;
    with Image1.Canvas do
    begin
    Pen.Color := clRed;
    Pen.Width := 1;
    MoveTo(x0, 0);
    LineTo(x0, ClientHeight);
    MoveTo(0, y0);
    LineTo(ClientWidth, y0);
    end;
    y:=1/a*((b*b-1)/(b*b+1));
    x:= (a*b)*((b*b-1)/(b*b+1));
    Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(Trunc (x), Trunc(y));
    repeat
    b:=b+0.1;
    y:= a*((b*b-1)/(b*b+1));
    x:= (a*b)*((b*b-1)/(b*b+1));
    Image1.Canvas.LineTo(Trunc(x * mash)+x0, Trunc(y * mash) + y0);
    until b>=10;
   end;
```

Comment: И что получилось?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/iwynfl

Comment: Проблема вряд ли именно в этом, но у вас в коде формулы для X и Y перепутаны.

Comment: Вангую что это учебное задание, а решение из другого варианта задания.

Comment: Нет, не угадал) Плохой ванговальщик из тебя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас неправильно введены формулы.
2. А вы верно выбираете коэффициенты параметризации и границы параметра?

Вот, к примеру, мой вариант кода и картинка:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  mash = 100;
var
  x0,y0:integer;
  x,y,a,b:double;
  tt:double;
begin
    a:=1; // мне лень вставлять и обрабатывать Edit, я просто ручками в коде
    b:=-10; // задал значения для a и b, сами сделаете, как надо
// более того, раз уж мы идём по параметру до 10, значит, начинаться он должен с минус 10 (!)
    x0:=Image1.Width div 2;
    y0:=Image1.Height div 2;
    with Image1.Canvas do
       begin
         Pen.Color := clRed;
         Pen.Width := 1;
         MoveTo(x0, 0);
         LineTo(x0, ClientHeight);
         MoveTo(0, y0);
         LineTo(ClientWidth, y0);
       end;
    tt:=(Sqr(b)-1)/(Sqr(b)+1); // вычисляем общий член выражения, можно даже и на a умножить
    y:=a*b*tt;
    x:=a*tt;
    Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(Trunc (x), Trunc(y));
    repeat
       b:=b+0.01;  // шаг можно поподбирать, сделав больше, чтобы не делать лишних вычислений
       tt:=(Sqr(b)-1)/(Sqr(b)+1); // вычисляем общий член выражения
       y:=a*b*tt;
       x:=a*tt;
       Image1.Canvas.LineTo(Trunc(x * mash)+x0, Trunc(y * mash) + y0);
    until b>=10;
end;
```

И результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы график рисовался не относительно к центру координат, а в зависимости от вводимых значений, также менялась и прорисовка координатной площади? Допустим я по х введу -100, то мне не нужно пррисовывать координатную площадь до -100, а нужно вывсти квадрат от -90 до -120 к примеру и там показать график функции, которая была нарисована